# Find first and last index of minimum subarray which consists of the same symbols as initial string?

Tags: python, algorithm

For example, initially we have a string `abghjsag`, the answer should be 6(`abghjs`)
I wrote an algorithm which works for O(n^2), but can't figure out is there a solution which works for o(n) and can't find anything in google
Here is my solution:

```
def Subbaray(s):
    alphabet = set(s)
    substr = []
    for i in range(len(s)):
        for j in range(i,len(s)):
            substr.append((s[i:j+1],i,j+1))
    minlen = len(s)
    mini = 0
    minj = len(s)-1
    for subst in substr:
        if len(set(subst[0])) == len(alphabet):
            if len(subst[0]) < minlen:
                minlen = len(subst[0])
                mini = subst[1]
                minj = subst[2]            
    return mini,minj
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do this :

```
def get_subset(string):
    return ''.join(set(string))
```

and its <= O(n),the output:

```
jbhgsa
```

Comment: I think the task implies that the substring has to be continuous (we can't get indexes,e.g. from 2 to 4 and then from 5 to 6). Plus the return should be indexes

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

With the help of an array `f` with
`f[i][c]` denoting number of times symbol `c` appeared in substring `s[:i]`, you can check if substring `s[i:j]` qualifies as a potential answer (consists of all the symbols appeared in `s`) with the following procedure:

- for each symbol `c` in `all symbols`: check if all `f[i][c] - f[j][c]` is grater or equal than 1 (i.e., each symbol appeared at least once in the substring)

Then, using the two pointer algorithm:

```
j = 0
for i in range(len(s)):
    while not check(i, j):
        j += 1
    update answer with substring s[i:j]
```

The check function would be called O(n) times as `i` and `j` will only go through [0, len(s)) once.

The check function has a time complexity of O(m), in which m denotes the number of symbols, and initializing the array `f` is O(n*m)

The total time complexity is O(n*m). (But m is really small, so it's essentially just O(n))

Answer (score 0):

Create a dictionary with the characters as key, and their position indices as values, and then find and return the indices pair with the minimum difference:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def min_sub(s):
    chars = defaultdict(list)
    for i, ch in enumerate(s):
        chars[ch].append(i)
        if len(chars[ch]) == 3: #remove one
            if chars[ch][1] - chars[ch][0] < chars[ch][2] - chars[ch][1]:
                chars[ch].pop()
            else:
                chars[ch].pop(0)
    min_idxs = []
    min_len = len(s)+1
    for idxs in chars.values():
        if len(idxs) != 2:
            continue
        new_len = idxs[1]-idxs[0]
        if new_len < min_len:
            min_len = new_len
            min_idxs = idxs
    return min_idxs

min_sub('abghjsag')
[2, 7]

min_sub('abghjsaga')
[6, 8]

min_sub('abghjsagaa')
[8, 9]

min_sub('abcd')
[]
```

(Side note: the minimum substring in your example is from *g* to *g*, not from *a* to *a*)